# Тормозит автотест

Tags: java, testng

Занимаюсь написанием автотестов. Недавно стал очень сильно тормозить (работает по 3, 9, 49 минут, в зависимости от тестового стенда, когда раньше работал не более 2 минут) метод по созданию клиента (запись делает записи в БД, задействует SiebelDataBean). Ставил на паузу во время выполнения и всегда оказывался на методе socketRead0 класса SocketinputStream, хотя я так и не понял, как он взаимодействует, ибо не смог найти его использование ни с помощью инструментов idea, ни с помощью stackTrace. Методы, которые выдавал stackTrace, отрабатывали без задержек.

В общем, вопрос, как можно выявить проблему? (в идеале еще и решить)
Описание вери абстрактное, но более представить не могу.